# How do I get my icon to revert back to its previous color after I've clicked a new icon?

Tags: reactjs, icons, setstate, use-state

I am trying to make my icon change color upon clicking, which I managed to do with useState. Now however, I can't seem to unclick or uncolor the previously pressed icons. I read this has to do with setting a state which shows which icon is active and which isn't. If anyone knows how to fix this I would be extremely grateful with any help. This is my code so far, just in case it helps.

```
const Submenu: FC<SidebarLinkProps> = ({ item }) => {
  const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);
  const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);

  const [changeColor, setChangeColor] = useState('white');
  const [activeColor, setActiveColor] = useState(0)

  const IconOuter = styled.span`
  background-color: ${ changeColor };
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
`;

  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={showSubnav}>
        <IconOuter onClick={() => setChangeColor('#1F4782')}>
          
          {item.icon}
        </IconOuter>
      </SidebarLink>
    </>
  );
};

export default Submenu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to establish a kind of recent history of your state. Now there is no hook that does this out of the box but the easiest to create a history with is the [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) hook

**The general form of the `useRef()` hook is:**

```
const refContainer = useRef(initialValue);

useEffect(() => {
    refcontainer.current = value
}
```

**Here is how:**

```
const Submenu: FC<SidebarLinkProps> = ({ item }) => {
  const [subnav, setSubnav] = useState(false);
  const showSubnav = () => setSubnav(!subnav);

  const [changeColor, setChangeColor] = useState('white');
  const prevColor = useRef();
  const [activeColor, setActiveColor] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    prevColor.current = changeColor;
  });
  const IconOuter = styled.span`
  background-color: ${ changeColor };
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
`;

  return (
    <>
      <SidebarLink to={item.path} onClick={showSubnav}>
        <IconOuter onClick={() => {if (prevColor !== changeColor){
                                       setChangeColor(prevColor.current)                    
                                                                 }
                                        else {
                                        setChangeColor('#1F4782')
                                                                 }
                                                                 }}>
          {item.icon}
        </IconOuter>
      </SidebarLink>
    </>
  );
};

export default Submenu;
```